# Import outlook to excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, outlook

I need to access MS outlook and count number of mail I received from a user and to import that user mail content to MS Access, Any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [Ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void btnAccessEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    Form1 obj = new Form1();
    int xlrow = 3;
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

    worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "DATE: "+DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
    worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "TIME: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    worksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "S.No";
    worksheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Date-Time";
    worksheet.Cells[2, 3] = "Sender Mail Id";
    worksheet.Cells[2, 4] = "Subject";
    worksheet.Cells[2, 5] = "Content";
    worksheet.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
    //range.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbCadetBlue;
    //range.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
    //range.Font.Bold = true;
    //range.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
   // ArrayList cdata = new ArrayList();

    int mCount = myInbox.Items.Count;

    if (mCount > 0)
    {


        label2.Text = mCount.ToString();
        for (int j = 1; j <= mCount; j++)
        {
            if (((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem) myInbox.Items[j]).SenderEmailAddress.Contains("ramkumar"))
            {
                var outlookXcell = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem) myInbox.Items[j]);
                var mailSub = outlookXcell.Subject;

                var mailcontent = outlookXcell.Body;

                var senderemailid = outlookXcell.SenderEmailAddress;
                var dtime = outlookXcell.CreationTime.ToString();
                //  var sendernm = outlookXcell.SenderName;
                //obj.mailtoXcel(mailcontent, sendernm, senderemailid, dtime);
                worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 1] = j;
                worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 2] = dtime;
                worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 3] = senderemailid;
                worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 4] = mailSub;
                worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 5] = mailcontent;
                worksheet.Cells.WrapText = true;
                xlrow++;
            }
        }
        app.Visible = true;
        String sTemplatePath;
        sTemplatePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        workbook.SaveAs(sTemplatePath+"outlook Xcell"+".xls");//, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet);//, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        workbook.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: :->, Thanks for modifying. . .